# How can I make the weather information default to display the weather in the user's current location? Openweather map

Tags: java, android, openweathermap

I'm trying to make a basic weather app so this might be a long one.

I'd like the app to display the weather in the user's current location when it loads up. Also, I have an edit text where the user can search for a city and it displays the current weather for that city.

However, how can I data validate the edit text and throw an error message if they don't enter a city/ leave the box empty?

I have no idea how I can default the weather to the user's location. Can anyone help with this?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
package com.example.weatherapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView view_city;
    TextView view_temp;
    TextView view_desc;
    TextView view_hum;
    TextView view_pres;
    TextView view_wspeed;

    ImageView view_weather;
    EditText search;
    Button btnsearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view_city = findViewById(R.id.location);
        view_city.setText("");
        view_temp = findViewById(R.id.temp);
        view_temp.setText("");
        view_desc = findViewById(R.id.condition);
        view_desc.setText("");
        view_hum = findViewById(R.id.humidity);
        view_hum.setText("");
        view_pres = findViewById(R.id.pressure);
        view_pres.setText("");
        view_wspeed = findViewById(R.id.wspeed);
        view_wspeed.setText("");

        view_weather = findViewById(R.id.weathericon);
        search = findViewById(R.id.citysearch);
        btnsearch = findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);

        btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getRootView().getWindowToken(), 0);
                api_key(String.valueOf(search.getText()));
            }
        });
    }

    private void api_key(final String City) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+City+"&units=metric&appid=febe19d9086a360a7f9283cedac01bfd")
                .get()
                .build();
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try{
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) { }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                    String responseData = response.body().string();
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseData);
                        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("weather");
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);

                        String description = object.getString("description");
                        String icons = object.getString("icon");

                        JSONObject templ = json.getJSONObject("main");
                        Double Temperature = templ.getDouble("temp");

                        JSONObject hum = json.getJSONObject("main");
                        Double Humidity = hum.getDouble("humidity");

                        JSONObject pre = json.getJSONObject("main");
                        Double Pressure = pre.getDouble("pressure");

                        JSONObject wind = json.getJSONObject("wind");
                        Double windSpeed = wind.getDouble("speed");

                        setText(view_city, City);

                        String temps = Math.round(Temperature) + "°C";
                        setText(view_temp, temps);

                        String hums = Math.round(Humidity) + "%";
                        setText(view_hum, hums);

                        String pres = Math.round(Pressure) + " hPa";
                        setText(view_pres, pres);

                        String wspeed = Math.round(windSpeed) + " mph";
                        setText(view_wspeed, wspeed);

                        setText(view_desc, description);
                        setIcon(view_weather, icons);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setText(final TextView text, final String value){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setIcon(final ImageView imageView, final String value){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                switch (value){
                    case "01d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sun));
                        break;
                    case "01n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sun));
                        break;
                    case "02d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.suncloud));
                        break;
                    case "02n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.suncloud));
                        break;
                    case "03d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloudsun));
                        break;
                    case "03n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloudsun));
                        break;
                    case "04d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloud));
                        break;
                    case "04n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloud));
                        break;
                    case "09d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rain));
                        break;
                    case "09n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rain));
                        break;
                    case "10d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heavyrain));
                        break;
                    case "10n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heavyrain));
                        break;
                    case "11d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunder));
                        break;
                    case "11n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunder));
                        break;
                    case "13d": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snow));
                        break;
                    case "13n": imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snow));
                        break;
                    default:
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sun));
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
 btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mSearch = search.getText().toString().trim();
            if (mSearch.equals("")) {
                //Put Some Error like**
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Input City Name*", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getRootView().getWindowToken(), 0);
                api_key(String.valueOf(search.getText()));
            }
        }
    });
```

**Edit**
Here is the edit of your comment

First go to 'you package name'/right click/new/file/: name as CityNames.json (Rembeber to put .json extension correctly)

Then go to [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lutangar/cities.json/master/cities.json) site.

Copy all the data and paste it to the json file.

And make a method in your project

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(),FILE_NAME);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
while (line != null){
    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
bufferedReader.close();
// This responce will have Json Format String
String responce = stringBuilder.toString();
```

And parse the response as json type or leran about it, Its basic!

Then make a arrayList and store all the city names taken from json, and return it  from the method.

Then use the method to check if city is valid like this:

```
    for (int i = 0 ; methodName.size> i ; i++)
            {
                if (cityName.equals(methodName.get(i)))
                {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getRootView().getWindowToken(), 0);
                    api_key(String.valueOf(search.getText()));
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey Harsh, this is great! Thank you! However, this only solves the issue of the user leaving the edit text blank. Is there a way for me to make sure that they enter a valid city name? I know this might be difficult as there are thousands of cities included in the open weather city database.

Answer (score 1):

You should use (FusedLocationProviderClient) (recommended by google) to get the last user location as (Latitude & Longitude) stored in the user's phone. The OpenWeather's API has two parameters that you should send Latitude & Longitude in that API. Try this tutorial. it will help you. [How to track the current location](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-track-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-an-android-device-using-kotlin)

Comment: Hey A.R.B.N! Thank you for your reply! The only problem is that the link is for Kotlin and I'm using Java at the moment. I'm looking into the Lat and Long on openweather now!

Comment: it doesn't matter what language are you writing. can't you understand the Kotlin code? i guess it's time to move to Kotlin. by the way, it's google's doc for FusedLocationProviderClient: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient

Comment: No, I'm brand new to using android studio and I've never used Kotlin before. This is my first time using java so I don't understand Kotlin much. Thank you for your help though. I'm just still really stuck.